# jQuery each function for multiple carousels next, prev identifier issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm using the Owl Carousel for my site and want to use the carousel multiple times on one page, i have successfully achieved this using the .each, however the jQuery code i'm using, when clicking the previous or next buttons to show the item in the carousel it triggers all the carousels. Clicking the next/prev button moves the item in all the carousels.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {        
    $(".owlcarousel-slider").each( function() {     
        var $this = $(this);
        var autoscroll = $this.attr("data-autoscroll"); 
        if(autoscroll == 1) {autoscroll = true;} else {autoscroll = false;}

        $this.owlCarousel({
            autoPlay: autoscroll
        });      

        $(".next").click(function(){
            $this.trigger('owl.next');
        })

        $(".prev").click(function(){
            $this.trigger('owl.prev');
        })             
    });
});
```

I believe the incorrect code has to be this bit,

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    $this.trigger('owl.next');
})

$(".prev").click(function(){
    $this.trigger('owl.prev');
})
```

Unfortunaltly my jQuery isn't my strongest, i believe i'm almost there.

Thankyou

Comment: To begin with, take out your click listeners out of $.each

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your response, heres the updated code but still the same issue, http://pastie.org/8794785

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If someone else still got this issue, here is a working example:

**HTML Markup**

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
   <div class="item"><h1>1</h1></div>
   <div class="item"><h1>2</h1></div>
   <div class="item"><h1>3</h1></div>
   <div class="item"><h1>4</h1></div>
   <div class="item"><h1>5</h1></div>
   <div class="item"><h1>4</h1></div>
   <div class="item"><h1>5</h1></div>
   <div class="item"><h1>4</h1></div>
   <div class="item"><h1>5</h1></div>
   <div class="item"><h1>4</h1></div>
   <div class="item"><h1>5</h1></div>
</div>
<div class="customNavigation">
   <a class="btn prev">Previous</a>
   <a class="btn next">Next</a>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".owl-carousel").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.owlCarousel({
    items : 5
  });
  // Custom Navigation Events
  $this.parent().find(".next").click(function(){
    $this.trigger('owl.next');
  });
  $this.parent().find(".prev").click(function(){
    $this.trigger('owl.prev');
  });
});
```

Comment: But how can we use more than one prev and next button on the same page. I have two owl carousel with next and prev. When I clicked on first then it is slide but as well, as the second carousel is also sliding because of same name

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to test it myself, but try this.

Remove the part you said you think is wrong:

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    $this.trigger('owl.next');
})

$(".prev").click(function(){
    $this.trigger('owl.prev');
})
```

And add "navigation : true" to your carousel properties:

```
$this.owlCarousel({
    autoPlay: autoscroll,
    navigation : true
});
```

Comment: Hi, I should have mentioned my carousels are added dynamically via a WordPress shortcode, this is great if the user is limited to two carousels, this is why i'm using the .each jQuery and the settings for the owlcarousel are taken form the div data attributes.